# Spring boot JPA and Transactional : cannot reproduce a bug with a unit test

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-transactions, transactional

We have a method that adds a new record (credit card) and update an existing record. More specifically, we set the existing credit card as DISABLED and add a new one, created as ACTIVE.

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class CreditCardServiceImpl {

@Override
public CreditCard saveCard(Map<String, String> data, String cardType, String token, HashMap<String, String> card, String entityId, String fleetId, PspSettings pspSetting)
        throws ParseException, ClientProtocolException, IOException, AdyenUnAuthorizedException, org.json.simple.parser.ParseException, AdyenException {

    LOG.info("Check if creditCard  exists for entityId#{}", entityId);
    CreditCard creditCard = creditCardRepository.findByEntityIdAndStatus(entityId, CreditCardStatus.ACTIVE);
    if (creditCard == null) {
        creditCard = createCreditCard(data, cardType, token, card, entityId, fleetId);

    } else {
        LOG.info("Credit card#{} found, disable it and create a new one", creditCard.getId());
        // disable the older card for this entity
        creditCard.setStatus(CreditCardStatus.DISABLED);
        creditCardRepository.save(creditCard);
        // create a new card for this entity
        creditCard = createCreditCard(data, cardType, token, card, entityId, fleetId);  
// ***** SMELLLY ***

    }

    return creditCard;
}
```

that calls this `createCreditCard` method:

```
private CreditCard createCreditCard(Map<String, String> data, String cardType, String token, HashMap card, String entityId, String fleetId) throws ParseException {
        LOG.info("Creating new card");
        CreditCard creditCard = new CreditCard();
        creditCard.setCardSummary(data.get("cardSummary"));
        creditCard.setFleetId(fleetId);
        if (data.get("expiryDate") != null) {
            creditCard.setExpiryDate(formatter.parse(data.get("expiryDate")));
        }
        creditCard.setCardType(cardType);
        creditCard.setToken(token);
        creditCard.setEntityId(entityId);
        creditCard.setStatus(CreditCardStatus.ACTIVE);
        if (card != null) {
            creditCard.setHolderName((String) card.get("holderName"));
        }
        LOG.info("Saving card# {}", creditCard.toString());
        creditCardRepository.save(creditCard);
        return creditCard;
    }

}
```

We have a bug where we end up with two credit cards in the DB that are identical, both set as ACTIVE.

I suspect it s because we reuse the local creditCard var. (see the *** SMELLY ** line above)

So I think this can easily be fixed by using another local var instead of creditCard.

The troubling issue is that I cannot reproduce this in the unit test.

The below test passes.

```
@Test
    public void disableAdyenTokenTest()  {

        //save a card first and then check that it exists to disable it
        EntityX entityX = new EntityX();
        // some stuff   
        entityX.setFleetId(BASE_FLEET);       
        entityX = entityService.save(entityX);
        LOG.info("----- save credit card for test -----");

        creditCardService.save(cc);

        Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();
        String cardType="visa";
        String newToken="0000000022";
        HashMap card = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Date date =  new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat formater = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/yyyy");
        String dateString = formater.format(date);
        data.put("expiryDate", dateString);
        data.put("cardSummary", "cardSummary");
        card.put("holderName", "Joe Louis");

        CreditCard ccReturned = creditCardService.saveCard(data, cardType, newToken, card, entityX.getId(), BASE_FLEET, settings);
        assertNotNull(ccReturned);
        assertEquals(CreditCardStatus.ACTIVE, ccReturned.getStatus());
        CreditCard activeCard = creditCardService.findByEntityIdAndStatus(entityX.getId(), CreditCardStatus.ACTIVE);
        assertNotNull(activeCard);

        CreditCard disabledCard = creditCardService.findByEntityIdAndStatus(entityX.getId(), CreditCardStatus.DISABLED);
        assertNotNull(disabledCard);
        List<PspTransaction> list = pspTransactionRepo.findAll();
        assertNotNull(list);
    }
```

Any idea how i can reproduce this issue in the unit tests?

Thanks a lot for having read this whole post already :)

***APPENDIX:***

CreditCard entity, with Id as PK.

```
@Entity
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class CreditCard implements Serializable {
    /** The Constant serialVersionUID. */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /** The id. */
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
```

....

**UPDATE**

The application runs with a MariaDB database whereas the unit tests run on H2 in memory db. Can this be why?

Comment: What does the CreditCard entity look like? What's it's PK/@Id?

Comment: @EssexBoy updating

Comment: i dont see the problem yet, but you should use the return value from save for further operations: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html#save-S-